# Editable table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview for entering the ingredients of a recipe in a recipe app. I want to be able to type in the ingredients in the tableview cell and then save it to display in another view controller - UILabel (dynamically created).

I found code to make an editable tableview where data can be inserted and deleted, but no code to be able to type in a tableview cell.

Is there a way to be able to type in a tableview cell? What is the best way to do it?

Additionally, all data entered needs to stored in the database using core data.

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image]

The tableview in the AddRecipeViewController is where I want to enter data. When I click save, the data should be displayed in RecipeDetailViewController Ingredients UIView.

Update:

I have created IngrdientsTableViewCell class for custom cell with a UITextField for entering text. But when I compile, the tableview does not display any textfield to type in. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Updated code:

IngrdientsTableViewCell.h

```
@interface IngredientsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ingredientTextField;

@end
```

IngrdientsTableViewCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    self.ingredientTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, 39)];
    self.ingredientTextField.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.ingredientTextField.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    self.ingredientTextField.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;
    [self.ingredientTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.ingredientTextField setPlaceholder:@"Type Data Here"];
}
```

AddRecipeViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.ingredientItems.count;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Ingredient Cell";
    IngredientsTableViewCell *ingredientCell = [self.ingredientsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   // NSManagedObjectContext *managedObject = [self.ingredientItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (ingredientCell == nil)
    {
        ingredientCell = [[IngredientsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        ingredientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [ingredientCell addSubview:ingredientCell.ingredientTextField];

    return ingredientCell;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just add a UITextView to your cell prototype. When editing stops update your data model. If all your controllers are using the datamodel, everything will automatically update.

Comment: I tried adding UITextField as well as UITextView to the prototype cell in the storyboard. It give the following error :  Illegal Configuration: Connection "ingredientsTextView" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.

Comment: Have you created classes for your prototype cells. If not create a class for each cell type and set the class in xcode in the class inspector. You should then be able to CTRL drag your UITextField into the header for the cell class to create IBOutlets. What are you doing to get the connection error?

Comment: I haven't created a class for the cell yet. But I guess to get rid of the error, I will have to create a class. Basically, I was looking for a way to without having to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextView` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a textField/View to your tableViewCell and just handle the text events like you normally would. I do something similar with TextFields.

```
UITextField *textField;
cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Name", @"Name");
textField = self.name = [self makeTextField:self.selectedUser.name];
textField.delegate = self;
self.name.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
self.name.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
self.name.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
self.name.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:self.name];
```

You will have to format the text field with constraints depending on your setup, but ultimately you will want to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the above code? I did not understand what is makeTextField, selectedUser and name doing here.